# How to combine the count for a distinct field data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

The result of my query:

```
SELECT SYS_Product, 
       CASE 
         WHEN MEMVendor_Name = 'Unavailable' OR MEMVendor_Name = 'unknown' 
           THEN 'Error' 
         ELSE MEMVendor_Name 
       END AS MEMVendor_Name, 
       COUNT(MEMVendor_Name) AS MEMVendor_NameCount
FROM  dbo.ahs_master_bc_system_mem_vendor AS V
WHERE (AHS_CurrentCfg = 1) 
and SYS_Product='Gen8'
GROUP BY SYS_Product, MEMVendor_Name
```

is as follows:

```
SYS_Product | MEMVendor_Name| MEMVendor_NameCount
_____________________________________________
Gen8          Elpida           1
Gen8          Micron           84
Gen8          Nanya            28
Gen8          Netlist          0
Gen8          Samsung          55
Gen8          SK-Hynix         86
Gen8          Error            0 <----
Gen8          Error            2 <----
```

Problem: how can I get the "Sum" of JUST the Error to be 2(0+2) still maintaining the counts of others:

```
SYS_Product | MEMVendor_Name| MEMVendor_NameCount
_____________________________________________
Gen8          Elpida            1
Gen8          Micron            84
Gen8          Nanya             28
Gen8          Netlist           0
Gen8          Samsung           55
Gen8          SK-Hynix          86
Gen8          Error             2 <===
```

I need the group by since these results will be combined with another query based on the SYS_Product and MEMVendor_Name

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `case` statement to `group by` as below

```
SELECT SYS_Product, 
       CASE 
         WHEN MEMVendor_Name = 'Unavailable' OR MEMVendor_Name = 'unknown' 
           THEN 'Error' 
         ELSE MEMVendor_Name 
      END AS MEMVendor_Name, 
COUNT(MEMVendor_Name) AS MEMVendor_NameCount
FROM dbo.ahs_master_bc_system_mem_vendor AS V
WHERE (AHS_CurrentCfg = 1) 
and SYS_Product='Gen8'
GROUP BY SYS_Product, 
      CASE 
        WHEN MEMVendor_Name = 'Unavailable' OR MEMVendor_Name = 'unknown' 
          THEN 'Error' 
        ELSE MEMVendor_Name 
      END
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I got the results as required. I did use a combination of Group by from your post and the modified case statment part from the below post.The Group by was the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `group by` to treat all errors equal:

```
GROUP BY 
        SYS_Product
,       case 
        when MEMVendor_Name in ('Unavailable', 'unknown') then 'Error' 
        else MEMVendor_Name
        end
```

Comment: this is identical in behaviour to the original query and has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Simply refer to the column *position* rather than the *name* in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    SYS_Product, 
    CASE 
        WHEN MEMVendor_Name in ('Unavailable', 'unknown') THEN 'Error'
        ELSE MEMVendor_Name
    END AS MEMVendor_Name, 
    COUNT(MEMVendor_Name) AS MEMVendor_NameCount
FROM dbo.ahs_master_bc_system_mem_vendor AS V
WHERE AHS_CurrentCfg = 1
AND SYS_Product = 'Gen8'
GROUP BY 1, 2 -- The SQL standard allows group-by to reference column position
```

Also note simplification of case statement and reformatting to a more readable format

Comment: SQL Server does not allow numbered fields in a `group by`

Comment: Interesting (yet another reason not to use SQL Server). This question doesn't indicate it is for SQL Server

Comment: The `dbo.` prefix is kind of telling

Comment: Thanks for your input. Since I am using SQL Server 2008 I couldn't use the group 1,2. But the output would be the same if I changed to the actual coulmns in the select list.